# переделать функцию swap

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_S = 10;
void create (int Arr[MAX_S][MAX_S], int collumn, int row)
 {
for (int currentRow(0); currentRow < row; currentRow++)
{
    for (int currentCol(0); currentCol < collumn; currentCol++)
        Arr[currentRow][currentCol] = rand()%100-50;
   }
}

void show(int Arr[MAX_S][MAX_S],int collumn,int row)
{
for (int currentRow(0); currentRow < row; currentRow++)
{
    cout << "(" << currentRow << ")";
    for (int currentCol(0); currentCol < collumn; currentCol++)
        cout << Arr[currentRow][currentCol] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
    }
}

void swap(int Arr[MAX_S][MAX_S],int collumn,int row)
{
for (int currentRow(0); currentRow < collumn; currentRow++)
{
    int mirroredCol = collumn - 1;
    for (int currentCol(0); currentCol < row/2; currentCol++)
    {
        if(currentCol % 2 != 0)
        {
           swap(Arr[currentRow][currentCol],Arr[currentRow][mirroredCol]);
           mirroredCol--;
        }
    }
   }
  }

 int main()
{
int row,collumn;
cout << "Введіть кількість рядків:\n";
cin >> row;
cout << "Введіть кількість стовпців:\n";
cin >> collumn;
int Arr[MAX_S][MAX_S];
srand(time(NULL));

create(Arr,collumn,row);
show(Arr,collumn,row);
swap(Arr,collumn,row);
cout << "\n\n\n";
show(Arr,collumn,row);

return 0;
}
```

Функция `swap` переворачивает строку, а нужно переделать чтобы переворачивала столбец.Как нужно изменить функцию, чтобы переворачивало столбец?

Comment: Вам просто надо каждую колонку "перевернуть"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто нужно "перевернуть" каждую колонку, то функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void swap(int Arr[MAX_S][MAX_S],int collumn,int row)
{
    for ( int currentCol = 0; currentCol < collumn; currentCol++ )
    {
       for ( int currentRow = 0; currentRow < row / 2; currentRow++ )
       {
           swap( Arr[currentRow][currentCol], Arr[row - currentRow -1][currentCol]);
       }
    }
}
```

Имейте в виду, что в функции `main`, вы должны проверять, что введенные значения для числа строк и колонок не превосходят константы `MAX_S`. А иначе программа может иметь неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Ой я забыл указать что только не чётные столбцы должны переворачиваться, извиняюсь

Comment: Но это легко сделать

Comment: Я просто добавил if(currentCol % 2 != 0) перед swap( Arr[currentRow][currentCol], Arr[row - currentRow -1][currentCol]);

Comment: @darkwoolf А это еще зачем?! Это условие приводит к тому, что переставляются только нечетные колонки.

Comment: Так и нужно было)

Answer (score 2):

Лично мне больше импонирует цикл с двумя переменными:

```
for(int i = 0, j = row-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
{
    swap(Arr[currentRow][i],Arr[currentRow][j]);
}
```